# node JS: Code for my situation not working as expected

Tags: node.js

I want to query sql to get the name and store it in an array.
Next time if it is present in array, then It should not query SQL.

But here it is querying each time to sql. 
How can I avoid this ??

```
var ids = [62519, 1, 2, 3, 2656, 82969, 36201, 82969, 78788, 82969, 97647, 82969, 53745, 54510, 60850, 82969, 29872, 51407, 29347, 105113];

    var cnames = {};
for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
    var nlid = ids[i];
    console.log(nlid);
// It should be != not !== according to my knowledge
    if (cnames[nlid] != undefined) {
        console.log('already present');
    }
    else {
        console.log('not present');
        getCname(nlid)
        function getCname(nlid) {
            sqlcon.query('select name from ss_newsletters where newsletterid=' + nlid + ' limit 1', function (err, rows, fields) {
                if (err) {
                    console.error(err);
                }
                else {
                    var x = rows[0].name;
                    cnames[nlid] = x;
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Nodejs is async, you need to use callbacks, but you run asynchronous code in synchronous loop.

Look at **async** module: https://github.com/caolan/async . There is async loops, like forEach or eachSerie.

Answer (score -2):

Node JS query function is asynchronous, so first remove the duplicates from the array and then start query.

The following code will remove duplicates from the array **ids**.

```
ids.filter(function(elem, index) {
    return ids.indexOf(elem) == index;
});
```

**Edited:**

Otherwise query synchronously. But it is not a good practice in node js.

```
var ids = [62519, 1, 2, 3, 2656, 82969, 36201, 82969, 78788, 82969, 97647, 82969, 53745, 54510, 60850, 82969, 29872, 51407, 29347, 105113];

var cnames = {};

getAllNames(ids.length);

function getAllNames(lastIndex) {
    var nlid = ids[lastIndex];
    console.log(nlid);

    if(lastIndex <= 0) // fully iterated
        return;

    if (cnames[nlid] !== undefined) {
        console.log('already present');
    } else {
        console.log('not present');
            sqlcon.query('select name from ss_newsletters where newsletterid=' + nlid + ' limit 1', function(err, rows, fields) {
                if (err) {
                    console.error(err);
                } else {
                    var x = rows[0].name;
                    cnames[nlid] = x;
                }
                getAllNames(lastIndex - 1); // Call Synchronously
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: That is my case in realtime.. I'll get the values repeatedly and i should not query for them... So I cannot remove duplicates